# Difference in flexbox behavior between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css, flexbox

The sample can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/GGYtM/ and here is inline code as requested:

```
<html>
<style type='text/css>
.flex{
  /* old syntax */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;

  /* new syntax */
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: -moz-flex; 
  display: -o-flex; 
  display: -ms-flex; 
  display: flex; 
}

.flex-direction-horizontal{
  /* old syntax */
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

  /* new syntax */
  -webkit-flex-direction:raw;
  -moz-flex-direction:raw; 
  -o-flex-direction:raw; 
  -ms-flex-direction:raw; 
  flex-direction: raw;
}
.flex-cross-align-stretch{
  /* old syntax */
  -webkit-box-align:stretch;
  -moz-box-align:stretch;

  /* new syntax */
  -webkit-align-items:stretch;
  -moz-align-items:stretch;
  -o-align-items:stretch;
  -ms-align-items:stretch;
  align-items:stretch;
}  
.container{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding:5px;
  background:#ecd953;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.button{
  width:70px;
  height:50px;
  /*margin:5px;*/
  background: #1b486f;
  color : white;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:5px;
}

.wrap{
  margin:5px;
}
​
</style>
<body>
    <div class="flex flex-direction-horizontal flex-cross-align-stretch container" id='root'>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="elem2" class="button">
      <span id="txt">2</span>
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In firefox the "root" div element does not grow to fit width of the parent element but occupies the room needed to fit the content - that's perfect.
However in Chrome and Safari the "root" div element grows to occupy the whole width of the parent container.
What's the reason of this difference? Ideally I would like to achieve FF behavior, it's perfect.

Comment: I have found that it's actually a bug in FF - http://oli.jp/bugs/mozilla/flexbox-display-inline.html and Webkit's behavior is correct. In order to get the desired result position:absolute can be added in the root box:http://jsfiddle.net/GGYtM/3/

Comment: And here is consolidated sample that allows to get the desired result in both of FF and Webkit: http://jsfiddle.net/GGYtM/4/

Comment: Seems like FF (v35.0.1) has fixed the first issue raised and is now consistent with Chrome (40.0.2214.93 m), Ironically the consolidated sample is no longer consistent in both browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You use

```css
display: flex;
```

However, if you want it not to grow to fit width of the parent element, but occupy the room needed to fit the content, you should use

```css
display: inline-flex;
```

For older browsers, you may need

```css
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
display: inline-flex;
```

```css
.flex {
  /* old syntax */
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  /* new syntax */
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ecd953;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.button {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1b486f;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="elem2" class="button">
      <span id="txt">2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```